# Reversing an array in a class does not change the order of the elements

Tags: java

I want to reverse the order of the elements of an array a Java by using OOP and performing the operation on the same array. So far I have done the following:

```
public class Array{
    private int count;
    private int[] v;
    public Array(){
        
    }
    public Array(int n){
        v=new int[n];
        count=0;
    }
    public int[] getV() {
        return v;
    }

    public void setV(int[] v) {
        this.v = v;
    }
    public void print(){
        for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
            System.out.println(v[i]);
        }
    }
    public void input(int n){
        if (count>=v.length){
            System.out.println("full");
        }
        else{
            v[count]=n;
            count++;
        }
    }
    public Array reverse(){
        int temp;
        int countT=count-1;
        Array a = new Array;
        for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
            temp=v[i];
            v[i]=v[countT];
            v[countT]=temp;
            countT--;
        }
        a.setV(v);
        return a;
}


//main
        Array a=new Array(5);
        Array temp;
        int min, max,valor;
        min=1;
        max=100;
        for (int i=10;i<=50;i=i+10){
            value=(int)(Math.random()*(max-min)+1);
            a.input(value);
        }
        temp=a.reverse();
        temp.print();
```

The issue that I found is that it always prints me the same array, I have checked it up the program, but I am not able to find the mistake.
Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is that you are iterating through the entire array from both directions (left to right and right to left):

```
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
        temp=v[i];
        v[i]=v[countT];
        v[countT]=temp;
        countT--;
    }
```

instead you need to iterate thought only half of the array from both directions:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count / 2; i++)
{
        temp=v[i];
        v[i]=v[countT];
        v[countT]=temp;
        countT--;
}
```

For an array with 6 elements `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` in the first loop you do the following:

```
iteration i = 0 : {6,2,3,4,5,1}
iteration i = 1 : {6,5,3,4,2,1}
iteration i = 2 : {6,5,4,3,2,1}
```

as you can see it is already in reverse, but you continue on:

```
iteration i = 3 : {6,5,3,4,2,1}
iteration i = 4 : {6,2,3,4,5,1}
iteration i = 5 : {1,5,4,3,2,6}
```

So basically you undo what you have done. Hence, why you need to iterate until `count / 2`.